# How can the page know I'm analyzing it with firebug

Tags: javascript, gmail, firebug, detection

Look:

[image: Screenshot of Google identifying Firebug use]!

Wow!

How can the webpage know I'm using firebug?

BTW I couldn't find out how to show the translucent add banner.

Comment: That is impressive. Google is good!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do:

```
if(window.console && window.console.firebug)
{
    alert("Firebug active!");
}
```

Comment: Never gonna work in latest version of firebug. ( `window.console.firebug` removed from latest version of Firebug ,`window.console` is always defined in latest FF  ) try `window.console.exception`

Answer (score 4):

This works not only from the Firebug console, but also from within the page:

```
if (document.getElementById('_firebugConsole'))
   alert("fire!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Both answers will alert if the Firebug user has activated the Console panel. If users disable the Console panel, but leave the rest of Firebug up, the alerts will not fire (because Firebug does not inject the console object in that case).

Comment: Yes, but it's the console -- with its scrolling display of errors/messages/ajax-calls -- that Google claims slow things down.

Comment: Well for once they are correct.  But I don't get it, why do you care about google's warning if you turn on debugging for their site?

Comment: Generic reasons to care: (1) They suggest a way to remedy the problem if such debugging actually does slow down the site too much.  (2) The fact that they detect it means that they can take counter-measures.  In fact, that warning **is** a counter-measure.  Personally, if I am trying to fix someone's busted-arse site, I don't want the freaking site fighting it. (Sites have tried to thwart innocent Greasemonkey scripts before, for example.)