# How to know if the client's browser has firebug enabled?

Tags: javascript, firebug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can the page know I'm analyzing it with firebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501170/how-can-the-page-know-im-analyzing-it-with-firebug)

This is question just out of curiousity,
When i was browsing gmail with firebug enabled gmail shows up a message that firebug has known to make gmail slow if not prperly configured. So was just wondering how they do it.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
  if (window.console && window.console.firebug) { 
         // do something if firebug 
         alert("Firebug running"); 
     }
```